# Start/Stop background scripts chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
    window.open(".....")
    chrome.cookies.getAll({domain: "......"}, function(cookies) {
                for(var i=0; i<cookies.length;i++) {
                    chrome.cookies.remove({url: "......", name: "STX_SESSION"});
                }})

            chrome.tabs.reload()
            window.open(".....")

    const interval = setInterval(function() {
            chrome.cookies.getAll({domain: "....."}, function(cookies) {
                for(var i=0; i<cookies.length;i++) {
                    chrome.cookies.remove({url: ".....", name: "STX_SESSION"});
                }})

            chrome.tabs.reload()
            window.open("......")
    }, 1200000);
})
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name" : "....",
  "version" : "1.0",
  "description" : "....",
  "permissions": [ "cookies", "tabs", "<all_urls>" , "http://*/", "https://*/"],
  "icons": { "16": "....", "48": ".....", "128": "...." },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "....."
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["script.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

This is my code. I would like to reset the interval or in other word stop the background script from running. Is it possible to do this by clicking on the extension icon?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stop the background script since you've used the default value for `persistent` but you can stop the interval.

You can add a click event listener to the extension's icon using:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() => { .. });
```

And to stop the interval use `clearInterval(interval)`.

Here is a complete solution:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() => clearInterval(interval));
```

In order for all this to work, you'll have to add `browser_action` to the `permissions` array in the manifest and make sure, the `browser_action` key doesn't have a `default_popup` key-value pair.

All in all, you should be using `"manifest_version": 3` I think manifest version 2 extension are no longer accepted for publishing on the Google Web Store.

Based on your comment, it seems that you want to toggle the interval on click, here is how you can do that (along with some refactoring):

```
function doStuff() {
    chrome.cookies.getAll({domain: "......"}, function(cookies) {
        for(var i=0; i<cookies.length;i++) {
            chrome.cookies.remove({url: "......", name: "STX_SESSION"});
        }
    });
    chrome.tabs.reload()
}
doStuff();
window.open(".....")

const interval = setInterval(doStuff, 1200000);
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() => {
    if (interval === null) {
        interval = setInterval(doStuff, 1200000);
    } else {
        clearInterval(interval)
        interval = null;
    }
});
```

Comment: I already activate the script with chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener((). So what I would like to do is the first click activates the script and the second stops it.

Comment: @eightmax In that case, you can do something like this in the `onClicked` callback function: `if (interval === null) { interval = setInterval(..); } else {clearInterval(interval); interval = null;} `

Comment: @eightmax I've edited my answer to address that.

Comment: He's right that you should upgrade to Manifest V3. Google has changed the timelines a few times, but in general we're trying to phase out V2.